Bold-only acronym headwords in their definitions
How do I make the acronym headwords in their definitions within acronym environment to be bold only and not both italic and bold in tufte-book class? I looked everywhere and tried many different things without success. It looks like this class affects the way acronym definitions appear too but I don't know what causes this.
Here is an MWE:
\documentclass{tufte-book}

\usepackage{acronym}

\begin{document}

\begin{acronym}
\acro{ABC}{ABraCadabra}
\end{acronym}

This is a sample paragraph of \acs{ABC}

\end{document}

The output looks like this:

Although I intend to have something similar to this in tufte-book:


The following line of code from tufte-common.def which is shared by Tufte-related classes was causing the problem of italicizing the acronym headwords.
\renewcommand*\descriptionlabel[1]{\hspace\labelsep\normalfont\em #1}
Just removing \em and putting the result in the preamble solved my problem.
\renewcommand*\descriptionlabel[1]{\hspace\labelsep\normalfont #1}
